# jQuery dont work to set css image source

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, ionic2

Hello I have the Problem that if I use this:

```
$('.tab-button-icon[aria-label="profile"]').css({"background-image": "url('myserver.com/image')"});
```

works but this if i want to change the url programmatically and set it new with a variable doesnt work.
Im sure that this.profilepiclink has the right url.

```
$('.tab-button-icon[aria-label="profile"]').css({"background-image": "url('" + this.profilepiclink + "')"});
```

This is how I use it:

```
export class MainActivity
{
  profilepiclink:string = "";

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,  private auth: AuthService, public menu: MenuController, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)
  {
     this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
     this.menu.swipeEnable(true);
  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    NativeStorage.getItem('loginprofilepicture').then( data => this.profilepiclink = data, error => this.profilepiclink = "http://myserver/image");
    console.log(this.profilepiclink);
    //$('.tab-button-icon[aria-label="profile"]').css({"background-image": "url('http://server/image')"});
    $('.tab-button-icon[aria-label="profile"]').css({"background-image": "url('" + this.profilepiclink + "')"});
  }
```

Comment: Try using jQuery's $(this)

Comment: how do you mean that im very new to jquery

Comment: this.profilepiclink - in there. Why are you sure that this contains the right value?

Comment: problem with link in `this.profilepiclink`. All code is correct

Comment: Where are you setting this.profilepiclink?

Comment: because in the console log i get the exactly same url if i use profilepiclink. I think Marcin has the right solution but i dont know how to use $(this)

Comment: You should not wrap `this` with the JQuery object as it does not have a `profilepiclink` property. You will get `undefined` if you do that.  Please explain what "doesn't work" means. Have you checked the final URL that you get with your dynamic code? What is that value?